# Firwall/Router/VPN/Load Balancer virtualization in production

Tags: networking, virtualization, firewall

Looks like every vendor (open source/commercial) is offering VMWare image. Some even have impressive benchmark numbers.

Is ESXi on a *capable machine* (Dual QC 8GB) able to serve as an alternative for an appliance in high load situations. I'm looking at 100Mbps 15000conn/sec 200,000 concurrent sessions.

Are there any additional performance / security considerations?

Answer (score 1):

Probably yes; but you'd really have to test your specific application to know with any certainty.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about what performance hit you take by adding a virtualization layer, the answer is not very much in the grand scheme of things. If it makes your administration significantly easier, whatever small looses you have will be worth it.

That being said, if you have trying to wring out the last few bits from the system and are pushing the limits of hardware, you probably want to spend the time to have as few layers as possible.

If your system running on bare metal will comfortably do the job, chances are adding virtualization to the mix will just make your life as an admin easier. If the bare metal would be hot to the touch, it might not be such a good idea unless you can comfortably add a bit more metal.